# Execute Go function from Bash Script

Tags: bash, go

Say I have a Go script, called script1, that has a function, function1, that does not take any inputs.

Can I call that function from a bash script?

Comment: _Must_ you name it `function1`, instead of building a standard `main` function?

Comment: I have a main function, function1 is separate from it.

Comment: The normal way you do this in the Go world is to create a `cmd/function1` subdirectory and put a separate `main` inside `function1`

Answer (score 1):

While you can add a `main()` function which would call your `function1()`, allowing a [`go run` a single go file](https://golangcookbook.com/chapters/running/one-off/), you also have an alternative:

- [`mkouhei/gosh`](https://github.com/mkouhei/gosh):  interactive Golang shell, which provides an easy-to-use interactive execution environment and enable to omit the `main` function
- [`nickwells/gosh`](https://github.com/nickwells/utilities/blob/master/gosh/_gosh.DOC.md):  allows you to write lines of Go code and have them run for you in a framework that provides the main() func and any necessary boilerplate code for some common requirements. The resulting program can be preserved for subsequent editing.